# Cannot access website after updating htaccess for forcing redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, yii2

I'm using yii2 advanced template for landkrone.com, and I want it to automatically redirect to https by editing htaccess. But after I edit it, it become inaccessible.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> landkrone.com took too long to respond.

This is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/font/(.*)$ backend/web/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/plugins/(.*)$ backend/web/plugins/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/images/(.*)$ backend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|font|plugins|images|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|fonts|uploads)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ frontend/web/fonts/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ frontend/web/uploads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|img|images|fonts|uploads|plugins|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I used this htaccess to my other website in other server and it works fine. Why is this not working? Please help...

Comment: look into the server error logs for details by logging into cpanel

Comment: My guess is that your rewrite rules have nothing to do with the server not answering to https requests.